# Eventlistner to work on single button javascript

Tags: javascript

I want the element to be highlighted only when "8k" is pressed not the other buttons,
I know `querySelectorAll` is the key but don't know what change to make?
Beginner here. **Thanks**

**Javascript**

```js
const image = document.getElementById("c4");
let timeoutID;
document.querySelectorAll(".side-nav button").forEach(item => item.addEventListener("click", dance));

function dance() {
  image.classList.add('highlight');
  timeoutID = setTimeout(() => { 
    image.classList.remove('highlight');
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
  }, 1000)
}
```

**CSS**

```css
.highlight {
  box-shadow : 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(218, 51, 119, 0.4), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  }
```

**HTML**

```HTML
<div class="side-nav">
  <button href="#" style="order:3">2k</button>
  <button href="#" style="order:2">4k</button>
  <button href="#" style="order:4">1080p</button>
  <button href="C4" style="order:1">8k</button>
</div>
<div class="column">
  <img src="../pics/-vine-3404474.jpg" id="c4">
  <img src="../pics/-alina-vilchenko-4550659.jpg" >
  <img src="../pics/-ceejay-talam-8836293.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: `I want the item to be highlighted` ok but where is `#c4` ?

Comment: added, please have a look

Comment: Can you explain what `href="C4"` means?

Comment: I was using <a> tags before to learn how the bookmarks work through id that's why added the ``href="C4"`` to 8k and when pressed it will go to the element assigned with the ``"id=c4"``, but someone suggested me to replace <a> with buttons for better sementics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dance` function is passed an event object when the click occurs, which has a `currentTarget` property that is the element that the handler was attached to that caused the event.¹ So you can check if it's the `8k` button and only do the highlighting when it is.

With your current HTML, you could do that with the text content or `href`:

```
function dance(event) {
  if (event.currentTarget.textContent === "8k") {
  // or: if (event.currentTarget.getAttribute("href") === "C4") {
    image.classList.add('highlight');
  }
  timeoutID = setTimeout(() => { 
    image.classList.remove('highlight');
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
  }, 1000)
}
```

...but I would add a class or data attribute to the element instead:

```html
<button href="C4" class="do-highlight" style="order:1">8k</button>
```

Then

```js
    if (event.currentTarget.classList.contains("do-highlight")) {
```

---

That same value is also available as `this`, but using the `event.currentTarget` property lets you not worry about what `this` value your function is called with.

Comment: Thank you so much for not just sharing the code but explaining it too, you are awesome.

Answer (score 1):

At the javascript level, there are small changes.
When you click on the button you get an event object.

```
function dance(e) {

if(e.target.innerHTML=="8k"){
  image.classList.add('highlight');
  timeoutID = setTimeout(() => { 
    image.classList.remove('highlight');
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
  }, 1000);
 }
}
```

Comment: Beware using `target` -- remember, `button` elements can have other elements inside them. :-)

Comment: you can also use currentTarget instead of the target.